# filtering to display the required item in the view

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to make a music tracker web application in angular 2 that shall have the following capabilities:
    View all music track details in ListView
    Add music track with details like Title, Genres, Rating 
    Edit specific track
    Add genre with its name
    Can rename specific genre
I am facing trouble in implementing the search feature to edit the track. I have the made the following files:

```
**TrackModel.ts**


    import {MusicModel} from './MusicModel';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
    export class TrackModel{
  id:number;
  title:string;
  rating:number;
  genre:MusicModel[];

}

**GetAllTracks.ts**
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {MusicModel} from './MusicModel';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';


@Injectable()
export class GetAllTracksService{
  constructor(private http:Http){}
getAllTracks(){
return this.http.get('http://104.197.128.152:8000/v1/tracks').map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
}
```

I have the following files for getting genre data

```
**MusicModel.ts**

export class MusicModel{
  id: number;
 name: string;

 constructor(id:number,name:string){
   this.id=id;
   this.name=name;
 }
  }
**GetAllGenre.ts**
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {MusicModel} from './MusicModel';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
@Injectable()
  export class GetAllGenreService{
  //  baseURL="http://104.197.128.152:8000/v1/genres";
    //tracks=[];
    getAllGenre(){
return this.http.get('http://104.197.128.152:8000/v1/genres').map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }
    constructor(private http:Http){}
}
```

This is the contents of app.component.ts file

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {GetAllGenreService} from '../shared/GetAllGenre.service';
import {GetAllTracksService} from '../shared/GetAllTracks.service';
import {MusicModel} from '../shared/MusicModel';
import {TrackModel} from '../shared/TrackModel'
//import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {FilterPipe} from './filter.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

tracks:TrackModel[]=[];
search:string;
genres:MusicModel[]=[];

constructor(private g:GetAllGenreService,private t: GetAllTracksService){}
ngOnInit(){
  //this.g.getAllGenre().subscribe((data)=>{
    //this.genres=data.results;});
  this.t.getAllTracks().subscribe((data)=>{
    this.tracks=data.results;
    console.log('this.tracks',this.tracks);

  });
}
}
```

I have created a filter pipe for implementing the search feature as follows:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {TrackModel} from '../shared/trackmodel';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';


@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(values: TrackModel, term?: string): TrackModel {
    //return null;
    if (term=== undefined)
    return values;
    return values.filter(function(value){
      return value.title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
    });
  }

}
```

This is the app.component.html file

```
<div>
<h1>
  Music track</h1>
  <form id="filter">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" name="search" />
  </form>
  <table border="1" class="mytab">
    <tr>
   <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of tracks|filter:term">
      {{item.title}}
      <div *ngFor="let genre of tracks.genres">
      {{tracks.genres?.tracks.genres.name}}
    </div>
      {{item.rating}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="add new track" name="add" (click)="addnew()">Add New Track</button>
</div>
```

I am facing the following issues:
1. I am not able to use the filter error is filter cant be applied to type value.
2. how do i iterate the music model inside trackmodel something like this is the expected output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9otJm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this:

`transform(values: TrackModel, term?: string): TrackModel {`

Need to be this:

`transform(values: TrackModel[], term?: string): TrackModel {`

Aren't you filtering the array, not a single value?

Comment: <div *ngFor="let genre of tracks.genres">
      {{tracks.genres?.tracks.genres.name}} This also does not print the genre for the given track. if there are more than 1 genre for a given track they must be serparated by |